# Error SQL INSERT INTO with Odbc Command C#

Tags: c#, odbc

Scenario:
I want to input data from textbox into the database based on microsoft data base (.mdb)
I already searching and find good clue and my result was here.
This Code below was inside command button click event:

```
using (OdbcConnection conn= new OdbcConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" + 
            "Dbq=C:\\BlaBlaBla.mdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;";
    conn.Open();

    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(
         "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES ('" + txtFIELD1Input.Text + "','" + txtFIELD2Input.Text + "','" + txtFIELDInput.Text + "' )", conn))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

And when I click the command button, I get unfriendly exception

> ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find
>   output table 'TABLENAME'.

That happened when I insert `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`. If I didn't insert that, of course nothing happens in my table target.
So what mistakes did I make in that code? What should I do?

Comment: Seems pretty friendly to me. There is no such table as `TABLENAME`.

Comment: But i already set up the Database.mdb with a Table named TABLENAME and there was a Database.mdb in my project folder too, yet i didnt make DataSet from DataSources

Comment: While you're correcting the code, use *placeholders*. This will avoid errors that can be caused from [accidental or malicious] user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
    "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES ('" + txtFIELD1Input.Text +    "','" + txtFIELD2Input.Text + "','" + txtFIELDInput.Text + "' )", myConnection))
```

change this into

```
   "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES ('" + txtFIELD1Input.Text + "','" + txtFIELD2Input.Text + "','" + txtFIELDInput.Text + "' )", Conn))
```

you define Conn as your connection string not "myConnection"

Comment: sorry, i forgot to edit the question code. actually my connection string in INSERT line is conn

Answer (score 0):

So i changed to OleDbConnection And My Problem Cleared,

```
using (OleDbConnectionconn= new OleDbConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\LOSERONE\Documents\DATABASE\Latihan1.mdb";
        conn.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand (
             "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) VALUES ('" + txtFIELD1Input.Text + "','" + txtFIELD2Input.Text + "','" + txtFIELDInput.Text + "' )", conn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Seems, to connected the database must same as the connection string in the properties on the targeted database.
Does anyone can tell me what is the difference OleDbConnection with OdbcConnection in .mdb database file?!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because sql connection's default database after login is not the same where your table 'TABLENAME' exists. Try to add database name before table like this:

```
INSERT INTO DBNAME..TABLENAME (FIELD1, FIELD2)
```

Answer (score -1):

> replace your myConnection to Conn